# 80's Yakuza Film

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm trying to remember the name of a film I haven't seen years.

Here are the bits I can remember (its been a long time since I seen it so the details are lacking)

- It involves the Japanese Yakuza (possibly different Yakuza gangs) but in America (I think).
- The main actor is an american cop trying to arrest a member of the gang or avenge someone.
- The main actor I think if I remember correctly always seems to travel about on a motorbike.
- I think the film ends with a gunfight at a graveyard or something like that and a motorbike chase.

Comment: Why are you sure it's from the 80s? This might help. :) Any piece of dialogue might help too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are thinking of Michael Douglas in [Black Rain](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096933/combined). He plays a NYC detective, probably crooked, who is sent to Japan to chase down a Yakuza gang boss who is trying to get into US Currency counterfeiting, something they don't discover for awhile.

He races street bikes on the NYC waterfront as a hobby, and as a way to make quick cash. Since he is spending way beyond his means, he is under investigation by Internal Affairs.

His NYC buddy during his Japan trip is Andy Garcia, who is killed as a warning to him. His Japanese counterpart detective never really trusts him, and Michael Douglas takes some liberties with the way he conducts the investigation in Japan, causing him to be expelled by the Japanese Police, an order he ignores.

The final scene has motorbikes chasing him in a Japanese vineyard.

Comment: The NYC bike races are kind of thrilling, since they are run under the East Side Highway, and amongst the pillars on the east side of Manhattan, near the South Street Seaport. There's alot of bobbing and weaving, dangerous maneuvers, etc.